# Как с помощью Sprite кнопки двигать объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Есть кнопка, которая должна при нажатие двигать мяч:

P.S.(Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии Sprite кнопки двигался объект а не при нажатии кнопки мыши в любой части экрана! )

[image: Как двигать мяч при помощи кнопки]

Есть примерный script, который должен двигать мяч:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    [DisallowMultipleComponent]
    public class Button : MonoBehaviour {
        [SerializeField]Transform target;
        [SerializeField]Direction dir;
        public float speed = 25f;

        void OnMouseDown() 
        {
            Vector3 pos = target.position;
            switch(dir){
                case Direction.FORWARD:
                    pos += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                 break;
    }
            target.position = pos;        
            }
        }
    public enum Direction 
    {
        FORWARD
    }
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, мяч двигается только на один шаг.
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку мяч двигался пока я не отпущу его, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц и он получит то т же один шаг но не на нажатии кнопки, а на отжатии)

Answer (score 1):

BtnDirection -- в инспекторе выберешь какое направление движения
ObjectToMove -- перетаскиваешь обьект который нужно двигать

```
public Direction BtnDirection = Direction.FORWARD;
public GameObject ObjectToMove;

private Direction _direct = Direction.None;

void OnMouseDown() 
{
    _direct = BtnDirection
}

void OnMouseUp() 
{
    _direct = Direction.None;
}

void Update()
{
    switch(_direct){
        case Direction.FORWARD:
            //логика движения ObjectToMove
        break;
    }
}

public enum Direction 
{
    NONE,
    FORWARD
}
```

Comment: А что за флаг? можно по подробнее?

Comment: любой bool часто назівают флагами)

Comment: А вы можете написать примерный Script? я был бы признателен

Comment: Извините, но во время нажатие на кнопки объект не двигается. когда вы с этим Script-ом запустили игру, получилось с помощи кнопки двигать объект?

Comment: я писал код не проверяя. Но здесь ошибится было не где. Начни с простого вывода в консоль "Debug.Log("Forvard");" вместо логики движения обьекта а потом выясняй что у тебя не так.